# Differential equation, Solution is a Bessel fucntion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, bessel-functions

this is my first post here. I knocked my head on a differential equation yesterday, this one:

$$
\frac{12 \nu}{x^2} \frac{S(x)''}{S(x)} = -\lambda^2
$$

Where $nu$ is a constant.
The book says the solution is a Bessel function. I have had a little exposure to the Bessel equation and functions, I know how a Bessel equation looks like and worked out the solution using the series method during a small part of a course on quantum mechanics. My problem here is that i don't see how this equations is a Bessel equation and therefore why the solution is a Bessel function of order $1/4$. I was even thinking to figure out the solution with the series method and see if that one looks like that Bessel funcion, but I think that would be stupid since I already did for the general case. It's something that should be automatic, like: this is a Bessel equation $\Rightarrow$ the solution is a Bessel function.

Some help? how can I see that is a Bessel equation? and why the solution is a Bessel function of order $1/4$?

Thank you fo any help in advance.

Comment: Is $\nu$ just a constant or some specific function of $x$?

Comment: Have a look at this page, anyway: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write that $\nu$ is a constant, i specify that in the original post now. I watch your link now. Thanks

Comment: I didn't find that very useful, I still don't get it.

Comment: Well, the solution of your differential equation (and its relation with the Bessel K function) is clearly written in the linked mathworld page. If you don't find that useful, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: I gotta say that the solution is clearly similar to the one propose in my text. The point is that the K in your link is a modified Bessel function, in my text it says it's an ordinary Bessel function. Sorry but i'm not really used to work with these kind of equations

Comment: Plus it says in special cases, i don't know which cases it's referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transformed form of Bessel differential equation is :
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(2p+1)x^{-1}\frac{dy}{dx}+(\alpha^2x^{2r-2}+\beta^2x^{-2})y=0$$
which general solution is :
$$y(x)=x^{-p}\left(C_1 J_{q/r}(\frac{\alpha}{r}x^r) +C_2 Y_{q/r}(\frac{\alpha}{r}x^r)  \right)\quad\text{where}\quad q=\sqrt{p^2-\beta^2}$$
$J$ and $Y$ denote the Bessel functions of first and second kind respectively.

See : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html (Eqs.3-5).

This formula can be derived from the standard Bessel differential equation thanks to changes of variable and function, but this is a boring calculus. Nevertheless, any relentless one can do it.

Now, comparing the above ODE to the presently considered ODE :
$$\frac{d^2S}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{12\nu}x^2 \right)S=0$$
we see that they are the same with conditions :
$$\begin{cases}
y(x)=S(x)\\
2p+1=0\\
\beta=0\\
2r-2=2\\
\alpha^2=\frac{\lambda^2}{12\nu}
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases}
p=-\frac{1}{2}\\
\beta=0\\
r=2\\
\alpha=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{12\nu}}\\
q=\sqrt{p^2-\beta^2}=\frac{1}{2}\quad\to\quad \frac{q}{r}=\frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus :
$$S(x)=\sqrt{x}\left(C_1 J_{1/4}\left(\frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{12\nu}}x^2\right) +C_2 Y_{1/4}\left(\frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{12\nu}}x^2\right)  \right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, i guess you noticed i'm an amateur and you had to work it all out for me. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need more help, let know exactly where you are stuck.